# The provided execution role does not have permissions to call DescribeNetworkInterfaces on EC2

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-iam, roles, policy

When I input any code in this function (e.g. `console.log();`) and click  "Save", an error occurs:

> The provided execution role does not have permissions to call DescribeNetworkInterfaces on EC2

```js
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  callback(null, 'Hello from Lambda');
  console.log(); // here is my code   
};
```

I bound the function with Role: `lambda_excute_execution(Policy:AmazonElasticTranscoderFullAccess)`.

And this function is not bound with any triggers now.

And then, I give the role `AdministratorAccess` Policy, I can save my source code correctly.

This role could run Functions successfully before today.

Does anyone know this error?

Answer (score 292, accepted):

This error is common if you try to deploy a Lambda in a VPC without giving it the required network interface related permissions `ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces`, `ec2:CreateNetworkInterface`, and `ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface` (see [AWS Forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=756727)).

For example, this a policy that allows to deploy a Lambda into a VPC:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
        "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
        "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
        "ec2:DescribeInstances",
        "ec2:AttachNetworkInterface"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: To add to the above comment, the same error also pops up if your LambdaExecutionRole does now have the AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole policy attached to it.

Comment: Can you be more specific than `Resource: *`?

Comment: Only 3 actions were enough in my case: `{Create,Describe,Delete}NetworkInterface`

Comment: To clarify this answer: this error can occur if you ORIGINALLY deployed the lambda without a VPC, and NOW you're trying to add the lambda to a VPC. Apparently, in this scenario, AWS doesn't include these permissions, presumably on the principle of "least privilege".

Comment: @falsePockets No, not really. [None of these actions support resource-level permissions](https://iam.cloudonaut.io/reference/ec2.html). You could possibly tack on global condition keys like `StringLike / user-agent / "aws-internal/*"` but IMO none of them are specific enough to significantly change the situation.

Answer (score 109):

If you are using terraform, just add:

```json
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole" {
    role       = aws_iam_role.lambda.name
    policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole"
}
```

Comment: Can you advice how to do this with `aws-sam` ?

Answer (score 58):

## via Managed Policy

- To grant Lambda necessary permissions to dig in to a VPC where a production RDS db resides in a private subnet.
- As mentioned by @portatlas above, the `AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole` managed policy fits like a glove (and we all know use of IAM Managed Policies is an AWS-recommended best-practice).
- This is for Lambdas with a service role already attached.

### AWS CLI

#### 1. Get Lambda Service Role

- Ask Lambda API for function configuration, query the role from that, output to text for an unquoted return.

  ```
  aws lambda get-function-configuration \
      --function-name <<your function name or ARN here>> \
      --query Role \
      --output text
  ```
- return, take **`your-service-role-name`** to #2

  ```
  your-service-role-name
  ```

#### 2. Attach Managed Policy `AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole` to Service Role

```
aws iam attach-role-policy \
    --role-name your-service-role-name \
    --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
```

## CDK 2 TypeScript

```js
const lambdaVPCExecutionRole:iam.Role = new iam.Role(this, `createLambdaVPCExecutionRole`, {
    roleName        : `lambdaVPCExecutionRole`,
    assumedBy       : new iam.ServicePrincipal(`lambda.amazonaws.com`),
    description     : `Lambda service role to operate within a VPC`,
    managedPolicies : [
        iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName(`service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole`),
    ],
});

const lambdaFunction:lambda.Function = new lambda.Function(this, `createLambdaFunction`, {
    runtime : lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_14_X,
    handler : `lambda.handler`,
    code    : lambda.AssetCode.fromAsset(`./src`),
    vpc     : vpc,
    role    : lambdaVPCExecutionRole,
});
```

Comment: "we all know use of IAM Managed Policies is an AWS-recommended best-practice" - the non-VPC managed policy for lambda execution used to grant full read-write access to all objects in S3. Don't use those policies without looking at them first.

Comment: This is lovely!
I got error messages using `ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole')`. Then saw that you needed to prefix it with `service-role`and that unblocked me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 50):

This is actually such a common issue.

You can resolve this by adding a custom Inline Policy to the Lambda execution role under the Permissions tab.

Just add this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
        "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
        "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
        "ec2:DescribeInstances",
        "ec2:AttachNetworkInterface"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

There's a full tutorial with pictures here if you need more information (*Terraform, CloudFormation, and AWS Console*) or are confused: https://ataiva.com/the-provided-execution-role-does-not-have-permissions-to-call-createnetworkinterface-on-ec2/

Additionally, a more recent sequence of steps follows:

1. Under your Lambda Function, select "Configuration"
   [image: Lambda Configuration]
2. Select "Permissions"
   [image: Permissions]
3. Select the execution role:
   [image: Role Selection]
4. Select "Add Permissions"
   [image: Add Permissions]
5. Create Inline Policy
   [image: Inline Policy]
6. Select "JSON"
   [image: JSON]
7. Paste the JSON above and select Review.

Comment: `"Resource": "*"` isn't great. Is there something more narrow we can use?

Comment: @falsePockets [same answer as to your same comment above] - No, not really. [None of these actions support resource-level permissions](https://iam.cloudonaut.io/reference/ec2.html). You could possibly tack on global condition keys like `StringLike / user-agent / "aws-internal/*` but IMO none of them are specific enough to significantly change the situation.

Comment: works like a charm,  ty!

Answer (score 22):

It seems like this has been answered many different ways already but as of this posting, AWS has a managed policy. If you just search for the *AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole* you will be able to attached that, and this method worked for me.

Here is the arn:

```
arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
```

Answer (score 12):

Just go to execution role -> Attach policy -> Search for 'AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole' and add it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30846153)

Comment: How is this different from the other answers suggesting you attach the `AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole`?

Comment: This short answer is direct to the point and solved similar issue.

Answer (score 11):

An example for Cloudformation and AWS SAM users.

This example lambda role definition adds the managed `AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole` and solves the issue:

```
Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
Properties:
  RoleName: "lambda-with-vpc-access"
  ManagedPolicyArns:
    - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole"
  AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
    Version: "2012-10-17"
    Statement:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - sts:AssumeRole
        Principal:
          Service:
            - lambda.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: this Answer is correct, Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

After a bit of experimentation, here is a solution using "least privilege". It's written in Python, for the AWS CDK. However the same could be applied to normal JSON

```
iam.PolicyDocument(
    statements=[
        iam.PolicyStatement(
            effect=iam.Effect.ALLOW,
            actions=["ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces"],
            resources=["*"],
        ),
        iam.PolicyStatement(
            effect=iam.Effect.ALLOW,
            actions=["ec2:CreateNetworkInterface"],
            resources=[
                f"arn:aws:ec2:{region}:{account_id}:subnet/{subnet_id}"
                f"arn:aws:ec2:{region}:{account_id}:security-group/{security_group_id}",
                f"arn:aws:ec2:{region}:{account_id}:network-interface/*",
            ],
        ),
        iam.PolicyStatement(
            effect=iam.Effect.ALLOW,
            actions=["ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface"],
            resources=[f"arn:aws:ec2:{region}:{account_id}:*/*"],
        ),
    ],
),
```

Answer (score 2):

Just cause there aren't enough answers already ;) I think this is the easiest way.  If you're using the web admin console, when you're creating your Lambda function in the first place, down the bottom just expand 'Advanced Settings' and check 'Enable VPC' & choose your vpc... Simple!  Before doing this, my connection to my RDS proxy was timing out. After doing this (and nothing else) - works great!
[image: Image of VPC setup for new Lambda function]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a *quick and dirty* way of resolving the error.

Open `IAM` on AWS console, select the role that's attached to the Lambda function and give it the `EC2FullAccess` permission.

This will let you update the Lambda VPC by granting EC2 control access. **Be sure to remove the permission from the role, the function still runs.**

*Is it more or less secure than leaving some permissions attached permanently? Debatable.*

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SAM you just need to add to the Globals in the Template, like this:

```
Globals:
  Function:
    VpcConfig:
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - sg-01eeb769XX2d6cc9b
      SubnetIds:
        - subnet-1a0XX614
        - subnet-c6dXXb8b
        - subnet-757XX92a
        - subnet-8afXX9ab
        - subnet-caeXX7ac
        - subnet-b09XXd81
```

(of course, you can put all in variables, or parameters!)

and then, to the Lambda Function, add Policies to the Properties, like this:

```
  BasicFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Policies:
      - AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
      - AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
```

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely a strange error, but are you sure the example code you added is the one you're using in your lambda?

Because in your code, you are trying to log something in your lambda after returning control via the callback. In other words, first you told your lambda that you're done. Next, while it is busy shutting down and returning your results, you try to do some logging...

So first, I'd try this:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log('this is a test');
    // do stuff
    callback(null, 'Hello from Lambda'); // only do a callback *after* you've run all your code
};
```

And see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Thanks! It's OK now. It seems some Lambda bugs. I did nothing, but two days after It's become OK.

Answer (score 0):

Also check your permission boundaries on your lambda execution role, that one got me.

Comment: What might be the issue there and how would you solve it? (Please edit your answer with details)