# Cannot fix "The provided execution role does not have permissions to call CreateNetworkInterface on EC2"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I tried the solutions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41177965/aws-lambdathe-provided-execution-role-does-not-have-permissions-to-call-describ) but it does not work for me. I am getting the error:

> **The provided execution role does not have permissions to call CreateNetworkInterface on EC2** (Service: AWSLambdaInternal; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValueException; Request ID: 4c8d047c-2710-4334-86cd-51b7467c6f08)

Here is the CloudFormation associated with the error:

```
EventLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Sub ${DeveloperPrefix}event-lambda-${Environment}-${DeployPhase}
      Handler: EventHandler
      Runtime: java8
      Code:
        S3Bucket: !Ref SharedBucketName
        S3Key: !Sub ${WorkspacePrefix}/event-subscriber-${AppVersion}.jar
        S3ObjectVersion: !Ref EventLambdaS3Version
      Role: !GetAtt EventLambdaRole.Arn
      Environment:
        Variables:
          retry_event_table_name: !Sub "${DeveloperPrefix}${AppName}-${RetryEventTableName}-${Environment}-${DeployPhase}"
          test_enabled: true # TODO: Remove once endpoint provided.
      VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - !Ref LambdaSecurityGroup
        SubnetIds:
          - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub ${VPCStackName}-SubnetPrivateL
          - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub ${VPCStackName}-SubnetPrivateR
      Timeout: 28
      MemorySize: 256

  EventLambdaRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Sub ${DeveloperPrefix}${AppName}-${Environment}-${DeployPhase}-EventLambdaRole
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: [lambda.amazonaws.com]
            Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: !Sub ${DeveloperPrefix}${AppName}-${Environment}-${DeployPhase}-EventLambdaPolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
              - Sid: DynamoDbPermissions
                Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - dynamodb:PutItem
                Resource: !Sub 'arn:aws:dynamodb:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:table/${DeveloperPrefix}${AppName}-EventRetry-${Environment}-${DeployPhase}'
              - Sid: LambdaVPCPermissions
                Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - ec2:AttachNetworkInterface
                  - ec2:CreateNetworkInterface
                  - ec2:CreateNetworkInterfacePermission
                  - ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface
                  - ec2:DeleteNetworkInterfacePermission
                  - ec2:DescribeDhcpOptions
                  - ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces
                  - ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfacePermissions
                  - ec2:DescribeSubnets
                  - ec2:DescribeVpcs
                  - ec2:DescribeInstances
                Resource: '*'
```

I have searched for an answer to this and have tried several of the suggestions found but to no avail. I am making any obvious mistakes? I fear I cannot see the forest for the trees right now.

Comment: Just a sanity check here - after a stack is created with this CF template, does the `EventLambdaRole` in IAM indeed have two policy documents attached, each with their respective permissions?

Comment: Yes @TomNijs, they do.

Comment: can you try with manage policy `AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole` instead of `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole` ?

Comment: The curious thing is that I have multiple Lambdas in this project and this is *the only one* where I changed this role. I inherited this code from another, so I haven't fully unraveled what was done, but why would only this one Lambda need this role while the others use `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole`?

Comment: It's interesting. I just cross checked with what I have. Basically, I am using almost the same as your CF, the only difference is that I am using `AWS:: Serverless::Function` instead of `AWS::Lambda::Function`

Answer (score 63, accepted):

As the lambda is running in VPC, you can use `AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole` instead of `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole`. Ideally, it should be the same as what you have. One advantage is less maintenance effort from dev ops view.

**! Important** The error is not warning us about permissions of the user, but about permissions of the ***role*** associated with the lambda function. Make sure that

1. you have a role for the lambda function and
2. this role has  `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole` permission policy
3. this role has Trust relationships like the following:

`

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must also include the `ec2:AssignPrivateIpAddresses` and `ec2:UnassignPrivateIpAddresses` actions in your permissions.

Comment: i was pinpointing access and thereby avoiding the managed groups. this is a more specific answer because these are the exact actions missing from op's example.