# AWS Lambda (NodeJS) > AWS Neptune = 403

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, gremlin, amazon-neptune

Currently attempting to connect to Neptune via NodeJS Lambda.
The code works to the point of `getUrlAndHeaders` in both libraries and I am getting response back and a connection is created, however, on attempt to insert/select, I get the 403.

- There is a policy attached to the execution role, either "neptune-db:*" or "neptune-db:connect", but neither work.
- All the same subnets are being used as a temporary measure
- The docs mention Neptune lives in EC2 instances, but not seeing any reference to them
- Confirmed that there are policies attached to said execution role for ec2: CreateNetworkInterface,DescribeNetworkInterface,DeleteNetworkInterface

What am I missing? I am working on testing other things in the process, but not gaining any traction.

Documentation:
[AWS Neptune - IAM Auth Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/iam-auth-policy.html)
[AWS Neptune - Temp Credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/iam-auth-temporary-credentials.html)

Code being used/modeled after:
[AWS Lambda Examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/lambda-functions-examples.html)
[gremlin-aws-sigv4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gremlin-aws-sigv4?activeTab=readme)

In Progress:
[AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole - SF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41177965/aws-lambdathe-provided-execution-role-does-not-have-permissions-to-call-describ)
[@aws-sdk/client-neptune - NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/client-neptune)

Comment: Do you have IAM Authentication enabled on your Neptune cluster? If yes requests to Neptune need to be signed with SigV4.

Comment: @Kelvin Yes it is. Is that not what the libraries are doing beneath the impl?
I see that ```getUrlAndHeaders``` calling aws4.sign. [https://github.com/shutterstock/gremlin-aws-sigv4/blob/master/lib/utils.js](gremlin-aws-sigv4/utils.js)

Comment: Yes just wanted to verify - I see you are following the code from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/lambda-functions-examples.html which should work. There are other reasons that a connection can still be blocked. For example if your organization uses AWS Organizations and the SCP policy does not allow access to Neptune. Also assuming SSL is enabled, your hostname needs to start with "wss://" which I have seen trip up a few people. If none of this helps we can dig deeper.

Comment: @Kelvin I can see in the AWS doc example that wss:// is already applied. However, the one example on the npm page for gremlin-aws-sigv4 ends up calling "https:" for "/status". That is using the class "AwsSigV4DriverRemoteConnection". I can tell that is the issue because it logs error on "undefined' for 'submit'. The property '_client' is only set when the status call is successful.

Comment: /status is a REST endpoint so would need to be called as HTTPS with SigV4 applied. Gremlin code that uses the Gremlin client (and does not send the query as a text string) needs the wss:// to indicate a secure web socket.

Comment: @KelvinLawrence I got debug enabled - "get Neptune status "https://<neptune-endpoint-name-writer>/status" (try #5). Ultimately code "AccessDeniedException". Going to confirm the ARN has what it needs. (Typo: stats > status)

Comment: Is that a typo or did you really use `stats` it needs to be `status` ?

Comment: That was a typo

Comment: @KelvinLawrence Maybe I missed this, but was installing the Gremlin console a hard requirement?

Comment: The Gremlin Console is not required at all if you are connecting from a Lambda to Neptune.

Comment: Were you able to get it working?

Comment: @KelvinLawrence Yes... within the custom module (Terraform) being used, the reference needed was the "resource-id" and not just any given ID.